# APEX authentication function in custom schema doesn't work

Tags: function, authentication, plsql, authorization, oracle-apex

In scheme settings page in section Login Processing, field Authentication Function is set to AUTORYZACJA (function name) 

Field logout URL: wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.logout?p_this_flow=&APP_ID.&p_next_flow_page_sess=4155:PUBLIC_PAGE

here is my function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION AUTORYZACJA (p_username in VARCHAR2, p_password in VARCHAR2)
return BOOLEAN
is
v_pwd_baza varchar2(4000);
v_liczba number;
begin
select count(*) into v_liczba from UZYTKOWNICY where upper(login) = upper(p_username);
if v_liczba > 0 then
select password into v_pwd_baza from UZYTKOWNICY where upper(login) = upper(p_username);
if p_password = v_pwd_baza then
return true;
else
return false;
end if;
else
return false;
end if;
end;
```

Loging using schema with this function does not work. Error is "invalid login credentials". I don't know what to do. 

I will appreciate your help with this situation.

Comment: Obviously, your function has to work well, so there is something else. Do you pass valid the login credential`? If I were you I would use the database authentication instead of your own authentication.

Comment: Consider to refactor your procedure like [this](http://pastebin.com/xFN9bALD)

Comment: Yes i've passed valid credentials. Selects within function work properely. The project i'm creating consists of users and groups of users and I do have to create it in way that allows to move users users between groups and every group have different tabsets visible. Is another way to implement such solution?

Comment: I've changed fucntion to refactored by You, but APEX still rejects credentials

Comment: Maybe something is wrong in application settings, page or APEX?

Comment: Test this function outside of apex, does it return true when you pass valid credentials?

Comment: I put into sql command: select autoryzacja('login','password') from dual; and apex returned: ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06553: PLS-382: expression is of wrong type. Could we go to the chat? I've never tried

Comment: Have you tried to find how to implement custom apex authentication? I found [this](http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2010/08/how-to-setup-custom-authentication-in.html) after 5 seconds I began the search.

Comment: I followed another materials, got stuck in them. I'm starting work on blog You posted. Thank You for helping, your time and interest :)

Answer (score 2):

You should also **always** use hashed passwords, don't store them in plain text.
See something like http://apexawy.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/custom-authentication-scheme.html

The ora-06553 you received was because you tried to reference a boolean in SQL (the return value) - SQL has no awareness of booleans. You would need to test using something like

```
begin
  if autoryzacja('login','password') then 
    dbms_output.put_line('true');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('false');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Add debug logging to your function.  This should show you where the problem is occurring.

If you are in apex 4.1 use a statement like:

```
apex_debug_message.log_message('username is: ' || p_username || 
    ' and password is ' || p_password);
```

For apex 4.2, use:

```
apex_debug.message('username is: ' || p_username || ' and password is ' 
  || p_password);
```

A statement like this at the beginning of the function, plus one each place you are assigning a value and inside each if should show you where things are going wrong.

Then click debug on the developer tool bar and try to login.  After it fails click view debug and you should see your debug messages in the log.